# Showing error when trying to upload data on firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on uploading data on firestore database, but when i click on upload button to submit the information filled in the form so that it should upload on the firestore database. I am getting an error and the data is not getting pushed on the firestore database, but the image is getting pushed on the storage. The link of the image of error is provided below.

[image: link of the image 1]
[image: link of the image 2]

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './RestuarantInfo.css';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { storage, db } from "../../firebase";

const RestuarantInfo = () => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
    const [ uniqueId, setUniqueId ] = useState(0);
    const [ name, setName ] = useState("");
    const [ imageRestuarant, setImageRestuarant ] = useState(null);
    const [ cuisine, setCuisine ] = useState("");
    const [ rating, setRating ] = useState("");
    const [ deliveryTime, setDeliveryTime ] = useState("");
    const [ serving, setServing ] = useState("");
    const [offer, setOffer] = useState("");
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
        e.preventDefault();
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`/images/${imageRestuarant.name}`).put(imageRestuarant);
        uploadTask.on(
            "state_change",
            (snapshot) => { 
                // progress function
                const progress = Math.round(
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes)*100
                );
                setProgress(progress);
            },
            (error) => {
                // Error function 
                alert(error);
            },
            () => { 
                storage
                    .ref("images")
                    .child(imageRestuarant.name)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then((url) => {
                        setUrl(url);

                        // saving data in database
                        db.collection("RestuarantInfo").add({
                            imageUrl: url,
                            uniqueId: uniqueId,
                            name: name,
                            cuisine: cuisine,
                            rating: rating,
                            deliveryTime: deliveryTime,
                            serving: serving,
                            offer: offer,
                            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                        });
                    });
                setUrl("");
                setUniqueId(0);
                setName("");
                setCuisine("");
                setRating("");
                setDeliveryTime("");
                setServing("");
                setOffer("");  
                setImageRestuarant(null);
                setProgress(0);
            }  
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="RestuarantInfo_take_input">
            <h1>Restuarant Info</h1>
            <form>
                <label>Unique Id :</label>
                <br />
                <input type="number" name="uniqueId" value={uniqueId} className="RestuarantInfo_input" onChange={(e) => { setUniqueId(e.target.value) }} />
                <br />
                <label>Name :</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="name" value={name} className="RestuarantInfo_input" onChange={(e) => { setName(e.target.value) }} />
                <br />
                <label>Image :</label>
                <br />
                <input type="file" name="imageRestuarant" className="RestuarantInfo_input" onChange={(e) => { setImageRestuarant(e.target.files[0]) }} />
                <br />
                <label>Cuisine :</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="cuisine" value={cuisine} className="RestuarantInfo_input" onChange={(e) => { setCuisine(e.target.value) }} />
                <br />
                <label>Rating :</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="rating" value={rating} className="RestuarantInfo_input" onChange={(e) => { setRating(e.target.value) }} />
                <br />
                <label>Delivery time :</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="deliveryTime" value={deliveryTime} className="RestuarantInfo_input" onChange={(e) => { setDeliveryTime(e.target.value) }} />
                <br />
                <label>Serving :</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="serving" value={serving} className="RestuarantInfo_input" onChange={(e) => { setServing(e.target.value) }} />
                <br />
                <label>Offer :</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" value={offer} className="RestuarantInfo_input" onChange={(e) => { setOffer(e.target.value) }} />
                <br />
                <button onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit" className="RestuarantInfo_upload_button" >Upload</button>
                <br />
                <progress
                    className="imageupload__progress"
                    value={progress}
                    max="100"
                />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RestuarantInfo;
```

Comment: `ref.put` is an asynchronous task, you should `await` for it

Comment: The event is called `state_changed`  (with a `d` at the end) not `state_change`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress